# How to add a transparent border to a WS_POPUP window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using Window 7 and I wanted to add a transparent border to my window. The same border as we can see on skype for instance.
Window Creation:

```
hWnd = CreateWindow(L"Example", 0, WS_POPUP, 100, 100, 400, 500, NULL, NULL, hinst, NULL);
```

Is there a way to add the transparent border to `WS_POPUP` window without the `WS_SYSMENU`?

Comment: Register the window class specifying the [CS_DROPSHADOW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176.aspx) class style.